# How to reference own class in scala?

Tags: scala, nodes

```
class Node(var x: Int, var y: Int, var prev: Node)
{
    def getpath(): String = 
    {
        var tempnode = this(prev);
        while(tempnode.prev != null) 
        {
            tempnode = tempnode.prev;
        }
        return tempnode
    }
}
```

This is the code, but it doesn't work, in the method getpath() I want to reference the current node class into a variable and then iterate backwards through the previous nodes, how do I accomplish this in Scala exactly?

Comment: `var tempnode = this`. As for Scala guidelines - do not use `;`, do not put `{` in next line, do not use `return`. Also, Your `getPath` is not returning a `String`.

Comment: Learning **Scala** is more than learning syntax, is learning a new way to think and design programs. it would be good to pick a course that introduces you to topics like immutability, pattern matching, higher-order function, etc, that would help you reach a more idiomatic solution to your problem.

Comment: @sarveshseri thanks, that's all I needed. Return/semi colons and formatting are just habits from previous languages, you people are seriously obsessed with syntax too much. If it works and it reads better then I see no reason to change it.

Comment: @K.Loeke that simply isn't correct. Things like `;` and `return` aren't simply syntactic markers. They are part of the semantics of the language. They change how the compiler interprets your code. Just because something works for the limited number of test you wrote it doesn't mean your code is correct. Language best practices exist for reasons beyond convenience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jwvh points (all good!) notwithstanding, your code as written seems to be looking for root/head rather than path.

```
case class Node(x: Int, y: Int, prev: Option[Node]) {
    @tailrec
    def head: Node = prev match {
      case Some(node) => node.head
      case None => this
    }
}
```

Or if you actually wanted path:
(this is similar to @jwvh's answer, but is *tail-recursive*, meaning that it gets rewritten as a loop at runtime, which may become important, when the length of your path is huge).

```
@tailrec
def path(acc: List[Node] = Nil): List[Node] = prev match {
    case Some(node) => node.path(this :: acc)
    case None => this :: acc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is Scala. We don't use `var`. We don't reference `null`. We don't need semicolons `;`, and we don't use `return`.

```
case class Node(x: Int, y: Int, prev: Option[Node]) {
  def getpath: String = 
    prev.fold(s"($x,$y)")(_.getpath + s" -> ($x,$y)")
}
```